# segmentation fault in Fibonacci series

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", n);
    int a[n];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

actually i am getting segmentation fault in this simple Fibonacci series problem.so,what's the remedy for that

Comment: `scanf` wants a pointer as parameter, use `&n`

Comment: You might want to compile with `-Wall` to have the compiler warn you about such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
scanf("%d",n);
```

with

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

In `C` when you `scan` something , you have to provide the **address** of the variable. In `C` address of a variable is obtained by `&` operator .

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
5
0 1 1 2 3
```